# How can i handle array index out of bound?

Tags: android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list of image in grid view.When i click the image it shows in full screen mood and with touch change one image to another just increasing position.here is the code for onTouchListener

```
private int position=0;
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
    {  
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
        {  
              position++;
              if( v == findViewById( R.id.full_image_view ))   
              { 
                   imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
              }
        }
        return false; 
    }
});
```

At the last image it it shows error that "it has stopped unexpectedly ".How can i handle the array of index bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are try to get index that not in your array.your `position must be less than array.length`

```
 if( v == findViewById( R.id.full_image_view ))
              {
                  if(position < imageAdapter.mThumbIds.length){

                    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

                 }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the index is valid (between `0` and `array.size - 1` inclusive) before attempting to access that element in the array.